# Windows api projection memory leak

Tags: rust, windows-runtime

I'm pretty new to Rust, and was playing around with the [windows runtime crate](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs), as I saw something that looks like a memory leak.

When I run this code (I left here only what matters):

```rust
use windows::Media::Control::GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager as SessionManager;

fn main() {
    while true {
        let manager = futures::executor::block_on(SessionManager::RequestAsync().unwrap()).unwrap();
    }
}
```

Every 5 seconds (more or less) the RAM usage grow by a whole MB!

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs/issues/2061) on Windows runtime's github project

Comment: Maybe not relevant here, but quick googling shows that there is at least one instance of a code sample using Python bindings to the same API encountering a similar issue: https://www.editcode.net/thread-601385-1-1.html

Comment: Interesting. It looks like it was fixed there

Comment: At this point, it may be worth raising an issue on Windows runtime's github project.

Comment: Good idea. Just wanted to make sure it's not a problem with my code

Answer (score 0):

From checking the docs, [RequestAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.control.globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssessionmanager.requestasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-media-control-globalsystemmediatransportcontrolssessionmanager-requestasync) states that it returns a **new** instance of the Session Manager every time it's called.

Since this is in a `while true`, I think you're just creating more and more SessionManagers. Perhaps you meant to do this in an async context instead?

Comment: That is true, of course, but rust drops the `manager` every iteration, so it's not supposed to grow

Comment: Ah true, I totally missed that - my bad.